# awk find missing number in sequence from file1 and append to column in file2 after match / extended question

Tags: awk, numbers, match, sequence

hi i am posting as reference to prev. question extended question for previously answered 
[awk find missing number in sequence from file1 and append to column in file2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719638/awk-find-missing-number-in-sequence-from-file1-and-append-to-column-in-file2) where i want to genereate next available number in sequence after comparing as well from both files column $1,$2,$3

i tried did it like this way

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0; next} $1 in a{print $0 && b[$NF]; next} {while(++c in b); print $0, c}' file1 file2
```

it just return below: just 2,3,4,5

```
A-5 ID2548 A550 SEQ.8232 md5 8232 71192160 COMPRESSED 5 false 0 verfied _xx 2
A-5 ID2548 A550 SEQ.8233 md5 8233 71192160 COMPRESSED 2 true 0 verfied _xx 3
B-8 ID3285 A400 SEQ.59060 md5 192 209763200 UNCOMPRESSED 1 false 0 verfied _xx 4
B-8 ID3285 A400 SEQ.59060 md5 193 262192000 COMPRESSED 16 true 0 verfied _xx 5
```

file1

```
A-5 ID2548 A550 85 S-38 COMPRESSED 1
B-8 ID3285 A400 81 B-22 UNCOMPRESSED 1
```

file2

```
A-5 ID2548 A550 SEQ.8232 md5 8232 71192160 COMPRESSED 5 false 0 verfied _xx
A-5 ID2548 A550 SEQ.8233 md5 8233 71192160 COMPRESSED 2 true 0 verfied _xx
B-8 ID3285 A400 SEQ.59060 md5 192 209763200 UNCOMPRESSED 1 false 0 verfied _xx
B-8 ID3285 A400 SEQ.59060 md5 193 262192000 COMPRESSED 16 true 0 verfied _xx
```

desired result:

```
A-5 ID2548 A550 SEQ.8232 md5 8232 71192160 COMPRESSED 5 false 0 verfied _xx 2
A-5 ID2548 A550 SEQ.8233 md5 8233 71192160 COMPRESSED 2 true 0 verfied _xx 3
B-8 ID3285 A400 SEQ.59060 md5 192 209763200 UNCOMPRESSED 1 false 0 verfied _xx 2
B-8 ID3285 A400 SEQ.59060 md5 193 262192000 UNCOMPRESSED 16 true 0 verfied _xx 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the [answer to your previous quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720159):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {vals[$1,$2,$3,$NF]; next}
    {
        while (($1,$2,$3,++incr[$1,$2,$3]) in vals)
        print $0, incr[$1,$2,$3]
    }' file1 file2
```

When reading `file1`, the key fields (`$1`,`$2` & `$3` in this case) are added to the array of already used values. They are separated by a comma – `awk` will use a special variable `SUBSEP` to implement a multi-dimensional array.

When reading `file2` the sequentially incremented variable is an array which references the associated key fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{vals[$1,$NF]; next} {while (($1,++incr[$1]) in vals); print $0, incr[$1]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?